# Bash: How to pass cookie in JSON format to curl

Tags: php, json, linux, bash, curl

I am struggling to attach a cookie JSON file to curl request in bash.

I know it can be done with cookie.txt but since I have it in the following pattern:

```
{"provisioning": "61d83f29bda251.85229990"}
```

The curl request:

```
curl -k -v -b cookie.json -F name=csr -F filedata=@${CSRFILE} https://prov.is.byl.com/cert_signer.php >${CRTFILE}
```

Is it possible instead of having to send it this way?:

```
curl -k -v -b 'provisioning=61d83f29bda251.85229990' -F name=csr -F filedata=@${CSRFILE} https://prov.is.byl.com/cert_signer.php >${CRTFILE}
```

Comment: second command should work

Comment: @anubhava yea but I dont want to send it this way.

Comment: The short answer is probably "no". But I bet there's a ninja out there that can use `jq` and possibly `awk` or `sed` to transfer the JSON into the required format in a one-liner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn your JSON cookies file into the proper string format expected by `curl` like this:

```sh
curl -k -v \
  -b "$(jq -r '[to_entries[]|([.key,.value|@uri]|join("="))]|join(";")' cookie.json)" \
  -F name=csr -F "filedata=@$CSRFILE" \
  https://prov.is.byl.com/cert_signer.php >"$CRTFILE"
```

The `jq` command transforms `cookie.json` into a cookie string in the `name=value;name2=value2;...;` format as expected by the `curl -b` option:

```sh
jq -r '[to_entries[]|([.key,.value|@uri]|join("="))]|join(";")' cookie.json
```

Here is the `jq` script itself:

```sh
# start populating an array
[
  # transform input object cookie.json
  # members and value into array entries
  to_entries[] | (
    # Create an array for each entry
    [
      # with object member key to become cookie name
      .key,
      # and value encoded as uri format in case it contains
      # characters not allowed in an HTTP header (like CR, LF, TAB, SPACE, ...)
      .value | @uri
    ] | join("=") # join this array entries with an equal sign
  )
] | join(";") # join array entries of cookie_name=cookie_value with a semocolon
```

Comment: @OmarAbdelrazik forgot to secure the cookie value with: `(.value|@uri)`